# Convert Json Array to .Net List wrapper

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I would like to convert following Json Array to .net list wrapper. Not sure how ca I do that.

Json Array:

```
[{"Name" : "SomeName1", "Age" : "20" },{ "Name" : "SomeName2", "Age" : "21"}]
```

My class is:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name;
    public string Age;
}
```

If I use `List<Person>` as my conversion type then everything works fine.

But what I would like to do is to convert above array to following class's object;

```
public class PersonList
{
    public string somefield;
    public List<Person> PersonList;
}
```

I am not able to convert my array to List wrapper object. How can I do that?

I do not have control over conversion method. I am using RestSharp library to execute my web request. When I call execute method, I would like to pass PersionList type for conversion and not List

Comment: `what I would like to do is to convert above array to following class's object` But your json string represents an array of objects, not an object containing array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to implement a custom JSON Converter.
Here is an example : [How to implement custom JsonConverter in JSON.NET to deserialize a List of base class objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030538/how-to-implement-custom-jsonconverter-in-json-net-to-deserialize-a-list-of-base)

Comment: How can a custom serializer convert using data that does not exist? (The wrapper class fields are not in the json)

Comment: you must override the ReadJson method from CustomCreationConverter.

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = /*deserialize json list here*/;
var result = new PersonList() { PersonList = list };
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for.

Comment: This really seems to be what you are looking for, but you just don't know it. Your jsom does not have the properties of the wrapper class - it has the properties of. List of person. It would be easy to construct your wrapper if you had "somefield" available.